# Controlling Lights with Enttec Open Dmx USB in java?

Tags: java, dmx512

I am starting a project in java where I want to control a Lights from my computer using a Terminal Window.  I am using a piece of hardware called an Enttec Open DMX USB Converter.  So I am writing this question, to ask the community if anyone has an idea of how to send data to this Enttec device to control lights.  Where would I start? I already know how to write terminal command aliases and execute .jar files so I don't need help with that.

What I have tried so far is to look at an open source project called "Open Lighting Project" that I know can control the device and learn how it works and how can possibly make my program.  But I got stuck looking at the java code folder in the Github Repository, trying to find a DmxData.java class that it says OlaClient.java is importing. So I am very confused where it is getting it from.

I have also tried looking at the developer tools on the Enttec Website, and they don't work.  More Specifically I looked at the file package called Java Wrapper, and tried running the test and kept failing every time with different errors.

These are the links:

**Enttec Device:**
https://www.enttec.com/product/controls/dmx-usb-interfaces/open-dmx-usb/

**Open Lighting Architecture Github Repository:**
https://github.com/OpenLightingProject/ola

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ported a DmxPy to Java a little over a year ago. It worked for my needs with an ENTEC DMX USB Pro. See if this works for you.

Link: https://github.com/trevordavies095/DmxJava

Instantiate: `DmxJava dmx = new DmxJava();`

Set a DMX address's value: `dmx.setChannel(dmx_address, value);`

DMX packet to be sent `byte[] dmx_packet = dmx.render();` You can now send the packet to the ENTTEC using whatever serial library you are using.

Comment: Thanks for answer!  Could you explain how you send the actual data to the Enttec Device? Basically, What Serial Library would you recommend?

Comment: @EthanPervere I used UsbSerial (an Android Library). I'm fairly certain you can use Java's serial library, however, I have not tried it myself.

Comment: I got data sending to the DMX lights I have but it isn't the right data.  So what I need to do is use the DMX512 Protocol here [link](https://tsp.esta.org/tsp/documents/docs/ANSI-ESTA_E1-11_2008R2018.pdf) which ETC pointed me towards. So how did you create real DMX data such as above?

Answer (score 0):

I use Juanjo's lib (https://sourceforge.net/projects/opendmxjavajni/). DMX512 protocol is pretty simple. Main concepts are:

Universe: you can choose any universe, starting from 0, up to ~65K. A universe is a isolated network of fixtures, and has 512 channels each. Most entry-level DMX/USB interfaces work with only one universe.

Channel: each channel supports an integer value between 0 and 255. Some fixtures use only one channel (for instance, a dimmer), some use more than one (an RGB fixture, using a channel for dimmer, and other 3 for red, green and blue, for instance), and some may get really complex, using a huge ammount of channels (ex.: a moving head). You'll have to understand what are the channels used by the actual fixtures you want to use (channel n: dimmer, channel n+1: red, etc.). Usually you can set the "n" value in the fixture configurations.

To connect your DMX/USB interface, use:

```
OpenDmx.connect(OpenDmx.OPENDMX_TX)
```

Usually, you'll want to run an infinite loop, in which you control what goes on each channel. Just update the DMX array (an array of 'ints'), considering that channel 1 will be at position 0, and so on untill position 511. The interface will keep updating your fixtures accordingly.

```
OpenDmx.setValue(channel,value);
```

Juanjo's lib has several examples that might be useful.

Good luck.